# Graphing, 2 conditions for x

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas to plot a few graphs of data from a file regarding the Supreme Court, I need to create a bar graph that shows the the number of votes in each "direction" for each justice. There is a column in the file titled "direction" that consists of either 1 or 2 to indicate that the position was conservative or liberal. I would like the graph to show up with each value on the x axis as "(justiceName), 1.0" "(same justiceName),2.0" and the y value is total for each of those values, how do I go about setting two conditions for the x-axis?

```
scdb_subset.groupby('justiceName')['direction'].nunique().plot(kind='bar')
```

I currently have this written and this is what it returns

[image: justice names on x axis but all have value of 2]

Comment: What happens if you put `value_counts` in place of where you currently have `nunique`?

Comment: pretty sure that worked, thanks so much!!

Comment: Seaborn is handy for grouping `sns.barplot(x='justiceName', y='Vote', hue='direction', data=df)` Not sure what your data looks but if it is longform the above will get what you need. https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html

Answer (score 0):

Where you currently have `nunique`, this is counting the number of unique values for each judge - but there are two possible values (1 and 2) and apparently they all have at least one vote of each kind.

`value_counts` should give you roughly what you want:

```
sc = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['b', 1], ['a', 1], ['a', 2], ['c', 1], ['b', 2], ['b', 1], ['b', 1], ['a', 2]])
sc.columns = ['justiceName', 'direction']
sc.groupby('justiceName')['direction'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```

[image: bar plot showing the desired effect]